# How to count and group by number of occurrences in a column containing comma delimited string

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax

I have a column like this:

| Data |
| --- |
| A,B,C |
| A,C |
| A,C,D |
| A,B,C,D,E |

and I want the following result.

| Data | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| C | 4 |
| B | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 1 |

How can I achieve this without splitting column in DAX?

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new table

```
Table =
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 'Table 1', "new", SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table 1'[Data], ",", "|" ) )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
            "alphabets", PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT )
        )
    )
VAR _3 =
    GROUPBY ( _2, [alphabets], "count", COUNTX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [alphabets] ) )
RETURN
    _3
```

[image: Solution]